# Negative Binomial Regression with Moderation Effect

Tags: r, regression, interaction, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

In H1, I predict the positive effect of a program on the consumer spendings. In H3, I want to predict the positive effect of a program on the number of referrals, while also predicting the positive effect of spendings on the number of referrals.

I just wondered if and how to perform a moderation analysis within a negative binomial regression. Are there any examples or best practices?

And how would I interpret it then?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sounds like mediation, not moderation. Consider looking into the `mediation` R package and its associated literature.